# Access Controls in RadComboBox ItemTemplate on server-side

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, telerik, radcombobox

I am using a RadComboBox for multiselect of items,for that i have used a check Box and hiddenfield in ItemTemplate of RadComboBox,This RadComboBox is within a grid,my mark up is as follows

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RESPONSIBLE DEPARTMENT" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <telerik:RadComboBox TabIndex="2" ID="rcbDept" runat="server" EmptyMessage="--Select Department--"
                                                        AllowCustomText="true" EnableScreenBoundaryDetection="false" Width="100px" EnableTextSelection="false"
                                                        Filter="Contains" OnClientDropDownClosed="DropDownClosed" OnClientFocus="ClientFocus">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk1" onclick="onCheckBoxClick(this)" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dept_name") %>' />
                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnColumn" runat="server" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <telerik:RadComboBox TabIndex="2" ID="rcbDept" runat="server" EmptyMessage="--Select Department--"
                                                        AllowCustomText="true" EnableScreenBoundaryDetection="false" Width="100px" EnableTextSelection="false"
                                                        Filter="Contains" OnClientLoad="GetControlId" OnClientDropDownClosed="DropDownClosed"
                                                        OnClientFocus="ClientFocus">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk1" onclick="onCheckBoxClick(this)" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dept_name") %>' />
                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnColumn" runat="server" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <%# Eval("dept_name")%>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100px" />
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100px" />
                                                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100px" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

this part is within a column tag of gridview
I am unable to access the hidden control value of the itemtemplate of Radcombobox on server-side
Any help will be highly appreciable.
Thanks in Advance!!!....

Comment: You have this template in a column of an asp:GridView or a telerik:RadGrid  ?

Comment: i have it in asp:Gridview,plz suggest what to do,thanks very much for replying

Answer (score 0):

Try likes this ,

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
 {
     string _rcbDeptSelectedValue = 
     (row.FindControl("rcbDept") as RadComboBox).SelectedValue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.FooterRow;

    RadComboBox rcbDept = row.FindControl("rcbDept") as RadComboBox;

    foreach (RadComboBoxItem item in rcbDept.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chk1 = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chk1");
        HiddenField hdnColumn = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hdnColumn");

        if (chk1.Checked)
        {
            //Item checked
            string str = hdnColumn.Value;
            //Access hiddedn field vale here
        }
        else
        {
            //Item Unchecked
            string str = hdnColumn.Value;
            //Access hiddedn field vale here
        }
    }
```

Let me know if any concern.